# Apple ID retrievable from App download within Cocoa Touch

Tags: cocoa-touch, unique

Hi
I'm working on an iphone app that needs to be maintain a somewhat unique identifier per download. Is there a way to retrieve either the Apple ID used to download the App or another identifier I can use to link all devices with that download to a remote database/service?

Basically I want a single instance of my custom-generated data sitting on whatever device is linked to a certain Apple ID. If iTunes signs any App that you download, using that checksum would also be an option.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

If you use IAP(In App Purchase), you can tie a users purchase to a single receipt, and verify that receipt against Apple's servers.

For App store purchases, as opposed to IAP, Apple allows, and pretty much forces a developer to allow their App store apps to run identically on as many devices as a customer can put their iTunes account on, with no information available to the app about whether this was the customer's first install or their Nth.  If that business model doesn't work for you, don't put the app for sale in the App store.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I am aware, there is absolutely no way to get access to the current signed-in Apple ID on the device. Your only real option is to maintain your own username/login combo that the user has to enter on each device they own.

Comment: True but one download can still be associated with up to 5 username/login pairs (if I don't provide a logout feature). I would like to limit that to 1 pair.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can get the Apple ID, but you can however get the current device's ID via the [UIDevice](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html) uniqueIdentifier method.

For example:

```
UIDevice *ourDevice = [UIDevice currentDevice];
NSString *uniqueIdentifier = [ourDevice uniqueIdentifier];
```

However, you should note the following (emphasis mine) from the above linked document:

> A device’s unique identifier
>   (sometimes abbreviated as UDID for
>   Unique Device Identifier) is a hash
>   value composed from various hardware
>   identifiers such as the device serial
>   number. It is guaranteed to be unique
>   for each device. The UDID is
>   independent of the device name. For
>   devices that use a SIM (subscriber
>   identity module) card, the UDID is
>   independent of the SIM card.
>
> **For user security and privacy, you
>   must not publicly associate a device’s
>   unique identifier with a user account.**
>
> You may use the UDID, in conjunction
>   with an application-specific user ID,
>   for identifying application-specific
>   data on your server.

Comment: I'm already using the UDID to identify each device separately but I still look like to limit one instance per download.

Comment: @Hendrik Apologies, you didn't mention it in your question so I thought I'd mention it in case you weren't aware. Fingers crossed you find a better solution. :-)