# How to identify user across devices on iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I am working on an app where user will be buying some "credits" as in-app purchases and use them to buy some services inside the app. As user can has more then one device I need to identify him across different devices.

I understand I can create some logging (and store user accounts on my own server) but I would like to avoid this. In best case I would like to use Apple ID but I can't figure out how can I access Apple ID inside an app?

I found similar questions here but no satisfying answer. I do not believe there is no chance to access Apple ID from the app (I don't need password, just the id) as I found something like AVMetadataiTunesMetadataKeyAppleID in AVFoundation but this framework seems to be only for Mac OS X.

Any suggestion how to solve this?

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753223/apple-id-retrievable-from-app-download-within-cocoa-touch

Comment: You could use the UDID of the device. As of iOS 5 it's deprecated (that's why I didn't list this as an answer), but it still works.

Comment: Guys I believe he's not asking for device identification but rather *user* identification across multiple devices - say I have an iPod (id A) and an iPhone (id B) but I'm logged in with the same Apple ID. How can his app detect that two of those devices are from the same user? As far as I understand there's no way to do that without implementing your own log-in system but I'm also interested what other approaches exist

Comment: As Nick says: I need one user but more devices.

Comment: Patrick Perini> Actually it is nice idea to tie it with a in-app purchase, however, I plan to give user some credits for free at the beginning so I need to solve it somehow before first purchase.

Answer (score 4):

Sorry. There's no way to do it without implementing your own authentication system on your own server. UDIDs are unique to each device and Apple does not give access to the iTunes user account whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

Other way is you can use facebook authentication in order to achieve that. Just connect you app with facebook api and u can keep their login address with some additional info.

Furthermore, it might be useful for your app if they can share your app with their facebook friends :p

Comment: It is also good idea. It is not solving my problem but I can at least provide some alternatives to creating new account just for my app.

Answer (score 0):

You can identify user with help of GameKit.